# Copying and rotating large table from Excel to Word without turning it into picture/wmf/

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007

What would be the easiest way of copying and rotating a table made in Excel, to Word without turning it into a picture/enhanced metafile/or something alike.

I know I can use the *Section Break routine*, but the problem is the table needs to go into a company frame (which I cannot turn onto a landscape), so I literally need to turn the table by 90 degrees.

Any way of doing something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is to do the rotation in Excel - rotate the text 90 degrees in the cells (Format Cells|Alignment|Orientiation) and then reformat- and paste from there. I don't think you can rotate such objects within Word itself - or at least I can't come up with a combination of text anchors and wrapping settings that allows this.

Or there might be come VBA that could help you?

Comment: YUCK!
But +1 because it would probably work (hope ldigas has a rotate-to-portrait monitor to work on that spreadsheet...)

Comment: Hey, you didn't ask for an elegant solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pasting a table directly into word, paste it into a MS word text box then you can rotate it how you like.